# С прописной или строчной М/московский?

Tags: орфография

В предложении "Был на концерте М/московского симфонического оркестра" Московский - с прописной или строчной?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если слово "московский" входит в полное, официальное название оркестра, то с прописной. Это имя собственное.

Если же речь об одном из московских симфонических оркестров - со строчной.

Например, Симфонический оркестр Москвы "Русская филармония" тоже московский симфонический оркестр, но, несмотря на наличие названия оркестра ("Русская филармония"), прописная сохраняется у первого слова официального именования.

Answer (score 1):

Да, здесь с заглавной. Без всяких "если". Слово "Московский" входит в название коллектива. И даже мне, человеку не сведущему в музыке, это название известно.
http://moscowsymphony.ru/
Они на сайте? правда, умудрились все три слова с заглавной написать, но это уже перебор. Сомневаюсь, что название именно в таком виде, с тремя заглавными, могло быть зарегистрировано.
Википедия это [подтверждает](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80).

Дополнение. 
Все прочие - московские и не очень - оркестры необходимо назвать как-то по-другому. По полному названию. "Московский Академический симфонический оркестр (им. Когана)", "Московский Государственный симфонический оркестр (для детей и юношества)" и уж тем более всемирно известный "Виртуозы Москвы" не назовут просто "Московским симфоническим".